# Android Login via facebook SDK on Samsung galaxy S4 device is failed, while it's working very well on Sony device

Tags: android, facebook

I've got this error when I try to login via Facebook SDK on Samsung galaxy S4, while it's working very well on Sony device.

is there any information why it happened on S4 device and working on Sonny, and if there is any solution to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got what is the problem, it was an issue in the FB app, while it was stuck, and unable to login to the FB app itself, and clearing the FB app data from the settings was fixed the issue, and now I can do login via FB in my app.